# Does OrderBy(item => false) affect list order?

Tags: c#, .net

Does OrderBy(item => false) affect array order?

I want to move certain element to the end of the array:

```
var numbers = new[] { 3, 7, 4, 1, 5 };
var result = numbers.OrderBy(item => item == 4).ToArray();
```

Does this solution have any side effects affecting the order of other elements (!=4)?

Comment: What do you mean by "side effects"? This works because it's sorting by the numerical value of a bool, which is 0 for false and 1 for true, in .NET. Are you asking whether the order will be retained for items that are not 4?

Comment: If your question is whether OrderBy is "stable", that is, retain the order for items with the same sort value, then see duplicate: yes.

Comment: @CodeCaster - whilst that may be "true" for certain values of true, it's actually sorting because bool implements IComparable<bool>. Nothing to do with any (exposed) "numerical value"

Comment: @Damien whoops, I may have confused a thing or two here, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @CodeCaster "Are you asking whether the order will be retained for items that are not 4?" - yes, exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is fine, results with true (4) will be at the end of the list, your result will be 3, 7, 1, 5, 4

Comment: Just because something looks fine for a small sample doesn't mean it's fine in general. As the duplicate explains, `OrderBy` was explicitly implemented to be stable

Answer (score 0):

There is no side effects, as `OrderBy` operates on `IEnumerable` which doesn't have any methods to mutate collection

Comment: This is true if you interpret "side effects" as "mutating the underlying collection". The OP probably means something else.

Comment: From Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) `has an observable effect besides returning a value (the main effect) to the invoker of the operation` , hence OP most probably means underlying collection, not the output sequence

Comment: I am not asking for an arbitrary definition, I'm asking what the OP means by it. There is no use in answering a guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster, but question includes a term `side effect`